# Найти одинаковые Id в связанной таблице

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос

Здравствуйте есть связанная таблица с полями movie_name | seller_name | unique_id. Эта таблица получилась с помощью объединения таблиц sellers и movies по полю unique_id. В этой таблица у меня есть несколько одинаковых id в поле unique_id. Это специально сделано. Мне нужно выбрать всех кто имеет одинаковый id. Вот что я пытался:

```
SELECT 
  p.seller_name , s.movie_name
FROM sellers p 
INNER JOIN movies s ON  p.unique_id = s.unique_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Но этот запрос вообще выдает неправильный результат, он не выдает поля с одинаковыми id. Скажите как правильно тогда сформировать запрос?

Comment: А в какой таблице то записей несколько с одним unique_id в sellers или  в movies ? Для одинаковых unique_id значения seller_name и movie_name одинаковые или разные ? Возможно вам надо добавить некоторый group by или получать сначала список неуникальных в подзапросе IN

Comment: @Mike в таблице movies несколько с одним unique_id  , но поиск нужно осуществлять в объединенной. Значения  seller_name и movie_name конечно разные это имя продавца и имя фильма, Мне просто получается что одной фамилии сопоставляется несколько фильмов. И я хочу выводить эти фамилии с фильмами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.seller_name , s.movie_name
  FROM sellers p 
 INNER JOIN movies s ON  p.unique_id = s.unique_id
 WHERE p.unique_id IN(
          SELECT unique_id FROM movies
           GROUP BY unique_id
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      )
```

Comment: о клас, спасибо то что надо